# can i connect my phone audio(headphones/mic) to computer's (mic/headphones) jack?

Tags: usb, audio, headset, connector, microphone

I would like to connect my Motorola phone, which is having common USB plug to charge and connect headset, to connect to laptop's mic and headphone.

So what I want is to connect

- mobile's audio (output signal) to computer's mic jack (input singal) and
- mobile's mic (input signal) to computer's headphone(output signal)

It's very practical but do we get a cable to connect it ... or do we have to make our own?

If products are available in market are there

- mini USB to 2x3.5mm (male) jack or
- 2.5mm 4 pole TRRS (male) jack to 2x3.5mm (male) jack

I do have an Imate phone which has a 2.5mm dedicated headset socket so even if I can get a cable of 2.5mm 4 pole TRRS (male) jack to 2x3.5mm (male) jack that will help me.

Answer (score 1):

There are three problems to overcome:

### Signal-level mismatch and Impedance mismatch

The simplest way to pass audio signals between devices is to connect line-in to line-out. Your devices lack line-in and line-out ports, so this isn't possible.

The signal needed to drive headphones is larger than the signal produced by a microphone. You should expect a lot of noise and clipping. It might be feasible to use a potentiometer to attenuate the signal.

The usual solution is a [Direct Injection Box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DI_unit) but you could try a pair of [Attenuating Dubbing Cord](http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2103841)s.

### Stereo vs Mono

You also need to convert **stereo** headphone signals to a **mono** microphone signal. Use a [stereo to mono adapter](http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2102690)

### Feedback Loop

By creating a signal loop, you run the risk of creating feedback (howl-around). Make sure the laptop outputs are not monitoring the microphone input.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I've seen any 3.5mm to 2.5mm cables, but there are many 3.5mm to 3.5mm cables available in most electrical stores. A quick [Google Shopping search yields some for £1](http://www.google.co.uk/#q=3.5mm+to+3.5mm+cable&hl=en&prmd=ivns&source=lnms&tbm=shop&ei=cATVTYXWG4fm0QHej6HzCw&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=5&sqi=2&ved=0CDwQ_AUoBA&fp=e2e851204c5c9af7&biw=1536&bih=746).

I have found this though:

[3.5mm To 2.5 mm Audio Headphone Jack Adpater Cable](http://www.amazon.co.uk/3-5mm-Audio-Headphone-Adpater-Cable/dp/B000VLLI18/ref=sr_1_20?ie=UTF8&qid=1305805780&sr=8-20)

You may be able to place this between the 2.5mm jack and the 3.5mm  to 3.5mm cable - but I have no idea if it'll work, and if it does, what sort of quality you'll end up with.

Answer (score -1):

it is very possible. I did it myself.

So you will need:

- 2 aux cables
- 1 Y splitter to connect phone to pc headset like this:

[http://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-headsets-separate-headphone-microphone/dp/B004SP0WAQ/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1454263366&sr=8-4&keywords=pc+headset+to+mobile+adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004SP0WAQ)

Now, you connect the line out from the phone (the "speakers") to the blue jack on your PC (line in). - so thats 50% of it, all of the audio from your phone will go to your PC.
Seconed, you connect the line in from the phone (the "microphone") to the green jack of the PC (line out).

Now all we need is a simple software twist. right click your speaker symbol -> recording devices -> line in -> properties. and set it up to 'listen' to your speakers.
for the second one - download voicemeeter. and set it up so that your PC mic audio is going to the "speakers" (where your phone mic is connected)